# Is it possible to have Circuit messaging SDK running in a native Android app?

Tags: java, android, circuit-sdk

I want to use Circuit by Unify messaging features inside a native Android app, being able to send messages, attachments, sharing the video camera, and everything else Circuit does, but with a native Java Android app and not a hybrid one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only SDKs supported are web (JavaScript) and iOS native. The native android SDK is being worked on and should be available later this year.